# Show $\int_a^b \lambda f(x)dx = \lambda\int_a^b f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, analysis

Hey i already know a proof for this but i have to proove it with the **definition of sums top and sums buttom.**

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be integrable. Show for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R:$

$$\int_a^b \lambda f(x)dx = \lambda\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

Comment: What is $g$ here ?

Comment: Write down the approximate sums with the same partition of $(a,b)$ for both $\lambda f(x)$ and $f(x)$. What do you observe?

Comment: im sorry g was in an other sentence

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you define $\int_a^bg(x)dx$, but I'll sketch a technique with one definition, as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g(a+k(b-a)/n)$, that can be adapted for others. Note that$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\lambda f(a+k(b-a)/n)=\lambda\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(a+k(b-a)/n)$$so, taking the limit,$$\int_a^b\lambda fdx=\lambda\int_a^bfdx.$$

Comment: im sorry g was for an other sentence in one excersise. only f

Comment: @sarahmathmatics67 Nothing you did inspired my use of $g$; I only said that so I could have a symbol that can denote either $f$ or $\lambda f$.

Answer (score 0):

if $\lambda = 0$ we are already done. assume $\lambda \neq 0 $ then . we assume we know that $\sup \Big[ c f(x) \Big] = c. \sup f(x)$  and $\inf \Big[ c f(x) \Big] = c. \inf f(x)$ when when $c >0$

assume $c>0$

$$L(\mathcal{P} ,c.f) = \sum_{i=0}^n \sup_{x \in [x_{i} , x_{i+1}]} c.f(x_i) (x_{i+1} - x{i})  = c. \sum_{i=0}^n \sup_{x \in [x_{i} , x_{i+1}]}.f(x_i) (x_{i+1} - x{i}) = c. L(\mathcal{P} , f)$$

similarly $U(P,c.f) = c.U(\mathcal{P} ,f)$

so for integrability we have that show that $$\forall \epsilon>0\,\, \exists \mathcal{P}  \,\,,\,U(\mathcal{P},cf) - L(\mathcal{P} , cf)= U(\mathcal{P},f) - L(\mathcal{P} , f) < \epsilon/c$$

Since we have that $f$ is integrable we can get such partitions.

can you prove it for $c<0$ ?